# Variable might not have been initialized when trying to do simple calculations with variables

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java, or coding in general, and I'm trying to make a program that will take two values x and y, and show the sum, product and quotient of the two values. When running this code, I get error messages telling me x and y "may not be initialized". But x and y are only defined later in the scanner. How do I fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float x;
        float y;

        float sum = x + y;
        float product = x * y;
        float quotient = x / y;
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            
            System.out.println("Enter a value for x: ");

            x = input.nextFloat();

            System.out.println("Enter a value for y: ");

            y = input.nextFloat();

        input.close();

            System.out.println("x + y is: " + sum);

            System.out.println("x * y is: " + product);

            System.out.println("x / y is: " + quotient);

    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing the operation right after creating the variables `x` and `y`(values havnt been assign yet). You should do the operation after assigning them values(after taking input from user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare the variables

```
float x;
float y;
```

assign values

```
x = input.nextFloat();
y = input.nextFloat();
```

then do the computation

```
float sum = x + y;
float product = x * y;
float quotient = x / y;
```

Without any values assigned, You cant do any computation on them.

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize the variables when delaying them. It's a good practice to initialize variables before computation.

.....

```
float x = 0;
float y = 0;
```

... code continues....

Also, it's advisable to do the computation of sum, equation, product, after you receive the values from the Scanner.

```
 input.close

 float sum = x + y;
 float product = x * y;
 float quotient = x / y;
```